# What is the structure of the network based on BasicRNNCell?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I wonder what is the structure of the Tensorflow's `BasicRNNCell` in recurrent neural network shown below? It seems to me that it is a neural network with 3 layers and 12 neurons. But I am not sure how this connections look like? I am not sure whether it is a Hopfield net?

```
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=12)

states_series, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell,inputs=batchX_placeholder,dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **one layer** of basic RNN cells, each having **12 hidden units**. The number of cells depends on your `batchX_placeholder` placeholder.

Here's an example:

```
n_steps = 2
n_inputs = 3
n_neurons = 5    
X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, n_steps, n_inputs])
basic_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicRNNCell(num_units=n_neurons)
outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(basic_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
print(tf.trainable_variables())
```

It prints...

```
[<tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0' shape=(8, 5) dtype=float32_ref>, 
 <tf.Variable 'rnn/basic_rnn_cell/bias:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

So it created *one* shared kernel matrix and *one* shared bias vector. The number of cells corresponds to `output.shape` (derived from `X.shape`), which is `[?, 2, 5]` in this example. So there're 2 cells.

If you wish to create multiple layers, you should use [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/MultiRNNCell) function that accepts the list of cells in each layer.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you a question based on existing source code?

Comment: I mean file `Currency_Market_Predictor_RNN.ipynb` from this repository https://github.com/alberduris/SirajsCodingChallenges/tree/master/Stock%20Market%20Prediction. It's ipynb extension so if you prefer code in other extension or pasted on pastebin etc. just let me know. I analyse this source code quite long time and I am not sure if I do it in a correct way. I would write to you how I see it and you would tell me if my reasoning is correct. There is used the same RNN about which I mentioned in the question. But obviously I will understand if you won't want to.

Comment: This seems like a new question. It'd better if you click "Ask question" and describe it in detail. It's inconvenient to discuss things in comments

Comment: I know but I would have to ask every question in separated topic and my questions are associated with RNN that I have described above.

Comment: For instance you have written that `n_inputs = 3` means number of inputs. In algorithm there is a line (`In [14]`): `batchX_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,truncated_backprop_length,num_features],name='data_ph')` so the equivalent of your `n_inputs ` is `num_features` in source code. I don't understand why it is equals to 4 because in source code there are 2745 lines of input data.

Comment: Yes, it is `4`. And `xTrain = datasetTrain[['Close','MACD','Stochastics','ATR']].as_matrix()` also has 4 columns, hence they match

Comment: So it doesn't mean number of rows of input data but it is a number of features of input data?

Comment: The number of rows corresponds to the batch size in a placeholder, which is `None` in your example. The training session iterates over all rows and feeds the batches into a placeholder. Batch size can be different, but there must be 4 columns, i.e. 4 input features

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163665/discussion-between-wahtdbogh-and-maxim).

Comment: Do you know the answers to the questions asked in chat?